# How can I use the RTP capabilities of libav?

Tags: libavcodec, libav, libavformat

I have my own media engine for RTP audio streaming and recording in a SIP platform. Now I need to implement RTP video streamig and recording support. I plan to use libav.

I have searched for documentation and code snippets of video streaming and recording using libav. And have also gone through http://libav.org/documentation.html but didn't get any clue.

Most of the code snippet (examples) found at other places related to libav are outdated.

I do not want to use RTSP capabilities and am only interested in the RTP interface. Are there any docs which I could refer to ?

Any help or pointer appreciated ...

Thanks,
Amar.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation/mail list talk about there is no difference in sending to file or to some url.
I succeeded to send RTP packets but they are not playable by any player